# Simple example of a distribution on +ve natural numbers with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 p_n < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{p_n} = \infty$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, elementary-probability

**DISCLAIMER:** This is probably too elementary and I haven't spent much time thinking about it (as I should).

## Question

What is a simple example of a distribution $(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n,\ldots)$ on +ve natural numbers (meaning that $p_n \ge 0\;\forall n =1,2,\ldots$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n = 1$) satisfying simultaneously

- **finite-second moment:** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 p_n < \infty$
- **divergent square root of probabilities:** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{p_n} = \infty$ ?

---

## Edit

User Stephan Lafon has given a really simple proof which deserves to be expanded upon. In fact one can proof a stronger statement.

> For any $\alpha \in (1, \infty)$, there is no distribution $p:=(p_1,\ldots,p_n,\ldots)$ with fintite $\alpha$-moment such that $\sum_n p_n^{1/\alpha} = \infty$.

*Proof.* Let $\beta := \alpha / (\alpha-1) > 1$ be the *harmonic conjugate* of $\alpha$. Define the functions $f,g: \{1,2,\ldots\} \rightarrow \mathbb R_+$ by $f(n) := 1/n$ and $g(n) := np_n^{1/\alpha}$. If $\sum_n n^\alpha p_n < \infty$, then one computes
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_n p_n^{1/\alpha} &= \sum_n (1/n) np^{1/\alpha} = \langle f, g\rangle
\overset{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\le}\|f\|_\beta\|g\|_\alpha = \left(\sum_n 1/n^\beta\right)^{1/\beta}\left(\sum_n n^\alpha p_n\right)^{1/\alpha}\\
&= \zeta(\beta)^{1/\beta}\left(\sum_n n^\alpha p_n\right)^{1/\alpha} < \infty.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such distribution. Proof: By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{p_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n}\sqrt{p_n} \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2p_n\right)^{\frac1 2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1 {n^2}\right)^{\frac1 2}$$

Comment: Great. Thanks, just chewed out something similar :)

Comment: Updated the question with a proof to a slightly more general claim. Yes, still Cauchy-Schwarz at work.